# How to get to my Gmail on a computer where someone has his Google account?

Tags: google-account

I am using a different computer than mine. I cannot get to my Google Account because that's the account of my brother which is registered.

Comment: open incognito window in google chrome and login as usual

Answer (score 1):

Open https://accounts.google.com/ and Sign in with a different account (a link at the bottom of the page).

Or login to your operating system (Windows?) with a different username.
Or just use another browser.
Or use incognito mode in Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the setup you have a couple of options.

If you're only checking this once then you can use "Private Browsing" / "Incognito Mode" in the browser to log in. Once you close the window your session will be ended and the original login will be left in place.

If this is a regular occurrence then you may want to try just using a different browser. E.g. if your brother uses Firefox then you could use Chrome, &c. This way you'll each keep your own logins and settings.

Answer (score -2):

Below your brother's email address, there is an option "add user." Just click it and log in with your own email address.